# PHP / Asterisk AGI Count number of digits from GetData

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

I am attempting to count the number of digits that a caller inputs when prompted.  If the number of digits input does not equal 10, I would like it to return to the beginning of the file.  If the number of digits input does equal 10 I would like it to continue executing the program.  With the code below, no matter the callers input, it always goes back to the beginning.  Can anyone give me some insight here?

```
begining: {

    $agi->stream_file('file1');
    $result = $agi->get_data('beep', 6000, 10);
    $numlength = mb_strlen(utf8_decode($result));
    if ($numlength < 10){
            goto begining;
    }

    else {
        $number= $result['result'];
        $agi->verbose("Number: ".$number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `if ($numlength < 10)` to `if ($numlength != 10)`

Comment: I have used that variation and it did not help.  The get_data function will only allow up to 10 digits to be input anyway.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which part of the array you are counting.  Add ['result'] to your $result variable.

```
$agi->stream_file('file1');
$result = $agi->get_data('beep', 6000, 10);
$numlength = mb_strlen(utf8_decode($result['result']));
   if ($numlength < 10){
           goto begining;
   }

   else {
       $number= $result['result'];
       $agi->verbose("Number: ".$number);
   }
}
```